# Probability of at least two being grey

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say we have $11$ grey and $15$ white mice, so $26$ in total in a container we can't see. We want to take $5$ of them home. What is the probability of **at least two** of them being **grey**?

1. 2 grey: The probability of the first being grey is $\frac{11}{26}$ the second grey is $\frac{10}{25}$, the last three white $\frac{15\cdot 14 \cdot 13}{24\cdot 23\cdot 22}$.
2. 3 grey: $\frac{11\cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 13}{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}$
3. 4 grey: $\frac{11\cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 15\cdot 14}{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}$
4. 5 grey:  $\frac{11\cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7\cdot 15}{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}$

And the probability of at least $2$ grey is the sum of these?

Comment: Yes,  but it would be less calculation to consider the probability that none are grey or only one is grey.

Comment: The best way to solve this problem would be to count the probability that there are NOT at least two gray (in other words, count the possibilities that have no grays or only one gray brought home) and subtract from 1 to get your answer.

Comment: In other words, what @DougM said. Sorry, your comment came up as I was typing mine!

Comment: So this is correcT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do the computations explicitly. Fix some $g,w\ge 0$, $g+w=5$, and the question is which is the exact probability 
$$P(g,w)$$
to choose exactly $g$ Gray and $w$ White mice. First, each such choice depends on the positions we make the choices, for instance, for $g=2$, $w=3$ we have 
$$\binom 52=\binom 53=\frac{4\cdot 5}{1\cdot 2}=10$$
possibilities to consider the "positions" we extract the corresponding color, the list would be

```
WWWGG
WWGWG
WWGGW
WGWWG
WGWGW
WGGWW
GWWWG
GWWGW
GWGWW
GGWWW
```

Let us fix one of the above patterns. Then we have $11\cdot 10$ possibilities to extract the two $G$ at the two places they appear, and $15\cdot 14\cdot 13$ possibilities for the $WWW$. So explicitly, the probabilities are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(5G,0W)
&=
\binom 50\cdot
\frac
{\color{red}{11\cdot10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7}}
{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}\ ,
\\
P(4G,1W)
&=
\binom 51\cdot
\frac
{\color{red}{11\cdot10\cdot 9\cdot 8} \cdot \color{blue}{15}}
{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}\ ,
\\
P(3G,2W)
&=
\binom 52\cdot
\frac
{\color{red}{11\cdot10\cdot 9} \cdot \color{blue}{15\cdot 14}}
{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}\ ,
\\
P(2G,3W)
&=
\binom 53\cdot
\frac
{\color{red}{11\cdot10}\cdot \color{blue}{15\cdot 14\cdot 13}}
{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}\ ,
\\
P(1G,4W)
&=
\binom 54\cdot
\frac
{\color{red}{11} \cdot \color{blue}{15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot12}}
{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}\ ,
\\
P(0G,5W)
&=
\binom 55\cdot
\frac
{\color{blue}{15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot12\cdot 11}}
{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let us use computer aid to see these numbers, here [sage](http://www.sagemath.org)...

```
sage: P = {}
sage: d = factorial(26)/factorial(26-5)
sage: for w in [0..5]:
....:     g = 5-w
....:     numer = binomial(5,w) \
....:           * factorial(11)/factorial(11-g) \
....:           * factorial(15)/factorial(15-w)
....:     P[w] = numer/d
....:      
sage: for w in [0..5]:
....:     print "P( %sG , %sW ) = %s ~ %f" % ( 5-w, w, P[w], P[w].n() )
....:     
P( 5G , 0W ) = 21/2990 ~ 0.007023
P( 4G , 1W ) = 45/598 ~ 0.075251
P( 3G , 2W ) = 315/1196 ~ 0.263378
P( 2G , 3W ) = 35/92 ~ 0.380435
P( 1G , 4W ) = 21/92 ~ 0.228261
P( 0G , 5W ) = 21/460 ~ 0.045652
sage: sum( P.values() )
1
```

The needed probability is thus

```
sage: P[0] + P[1] + P[2] + P[3]
167/230
sage: _.n()
0.726086956521739
```

Or (humanly much) simpler

```
sage: 1 - P[4] - P[5]
167/230
sage: _.n()
0.726086956521739
```

Comment: Why would the order matter

Comment: Try to solve the same problem with 3+2 mice.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that at least two are grey is *one minus the probability that at most one is grey*.

---

The probability that none are grey is : $\dfrac{15}{26}\dfrac{14}{25}\dfrac{13}{24}\dfrac{12}{23}\dfrac{11}{22}$ or in short $\left.\dbinom {15}5\middle/\dbinom{26}5\right.$

The probability that one is grey is : $\dfrac{11}{26}\dfrac{15}{25}\dfrac{14}{24}\dfrac{13}{23}\dfrac{12}{22}\times 5$  Since the order does not matter we count all the orders.  Or in short $\left.\dbinom 51\dbinom{11}1\dbinom {15}4\middle/\dbinom{26}5\right.$

Put it together